# Does Windows have something like journald on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, boot, logging

I have a Windows 10 installed as main OS on a machine. When I installed it fresh it would boot in like 5 seconds, but as time passed and new updates got installed, the boot times became slower and slower (it's not too slow, but compared to the fresh install it is). I am talking about the splash screen with the spinning circle.

I do most of my thing inside virtual machines, so I rarely install things in the main OS that could affect boot times.

I Was wondering if there's something like journald from linux that I can use on Windows to figure out what's taking more time to boot.

Comment: My Windows systems, my Linux systems, and my iPhones do not boot in 5 seconds - not even close. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So more like "something like bootchart"? (It does, but it's a separate download and I can't seem to remember the name.)

Comment: There really isn’t. If Windows is installed on a SSD boot times should be at most 30 seconds when an update isn’t being installed. If it’s take a few minutes after the system has successfully been logged into to become responsive that most definitely is software causing that behavior. Windows should have near instant start coming out of suspension state.

Comment: @user1686 do you mean Windows Performance Recorder? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/optimizing-performance-and-responsiveness-exercise-2

Answer (score 0):

Slow boots can arise from multiple sources.

1. Dying hard disks
2. Fragmented file systems.
3. Extra steps in the bootup process, eg more executables being loaded and initializing, and some possibly hanging.
4. Some other hardware problem.

If you're using an ssd, #2 doesn't happen.
If not I'd check to see if the disk is fragmented which successive writes and deletes can cause very quickly on a windows system.

Otherwise there is the general bloat of windows to consider, with every successive version some of the same uses, eats up tons of more space in ram and hard disk space and processing power. As an old mentor would say "Its a feature", he hated windows, and this was back in the days of NT and 98 and 2000. Not much has likely improved.

Check what i said first, then consider probing deeper.
It doesn't sound like hardware, first thought is either more is happening at startup or your filesystem is fragmented.